# How to create a class to get the json response of a service which returns in an structure like the following?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

The webservice return the following JSON string:

```
{"errorCode":0,"error":"","status":"OK","data":{"id":"1234A"}}
```

So to get a class that receives the response in a function like this that performs a post in Retrofit:

```
Call<UploadImageData> postData(@Header("Cookie") String sessionId, @Body UploadImageModal image);
```

I'd need to make a class like this;

```
public class UploadImageData {
    private int errorCode;
    private String error;
    private  String status;
}
```

But I'm lost in how I would have to declare the part that would take "data":{"id":"1234A"}, so it gets the data from there correctly.

How could I do this?

Comment: A `Map<String, String>` or another `class Nested { String id; }`.

Answer (score 2):

Since data is a nested object within the surrounding json object, you can include it as another class in your UploadImageData class.

```
public class UploadImageData {
    private int errorCode;
    private String error;
    private String status;
    private MyDataClass data;
}

public class MyDataClass {
    private String id;
}
```

Don´t forget setter methods oder make fields public.